# Change jenkins job credentials programmatically

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins setup with a big amount of jobs.
I'd like change all the jobs that clone from git with credentials X to credentials Y (which I already created)
Any way to do that programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't got a git credential helper configured (check with `git config credential.helper`), set one up (e.g. `git config credential.helper store`).

Then you can store a credential programmatically with

`printf "username=<your_username>\npassword=<your_password>\nprotocol=https\nhost=your.git.host.net\n\n" | git credential approve`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just doing a sed command on all the xml files in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs and replace the credentials id with the new id.
not so elegant but worked like a charm